# My Sql Database Backup

Tags: mysql, database, database-connection, database-backups

> HI All,
>
> I have a MYSQL DATABASE ,I want to create backup of this database into another machine(secondary) ,and to link the machine with original database(primary)
> Is there any way that if primary database fails then it pick from the secondary database.

EDIT:How is this possible in window OS

Answer (score 1):

its called as clustering, check

http://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/

Comment: Can you tell me how it can be implemented using windows?